# R package with different behavior depending on OS

Tags: r, r-package, rjava

Recently I got a very strange thing when I use same package in different OS
When I entered wrong argument to package method, Ubuntu or MacOS made a exception but Windows didn't.
(Left: Ubuntu, Right: Windows)
For your information, this R package depends on Java lib using rJava.
But not very sure, it can make OS dependency.

R package GitHub: https://github.com/shineware/RKOMORAN
Depending Java GitHub: https://github.com/shin285/KOMORAN

Is there any clue about this strange phenomenon?

Test codes are like below

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("shineware/RKOMORAN")
komoran <- RKOMORAN::RKOMORAN$new(model_type = "STABLE")
komoran$set_user_dic("/foo/bar/wrong/path")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to compare versions of R, the `rJava` package on each, and Java on each computer to see where differences might be. (I don't use `rJava`, so I can't help beyond that, sorry. Just thought it might start you on the next step of troubleshooting.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing missing things! But when I tried same environment (rJava: 0.9-12 and JDK: AdoptOpenJDK8), Windows didn't raise any exception and didn't operate well...